# Criar input com valor fixo

Tags: html

Pretendo criar um `input` para inserir contatos de telemóvel.

```html
<h5>
  <strong>Contato</strong>
</h5>
<input type="text" id="Contato" name="Contato" value="351" 
       style="width:150px" required />
```

Pretendo que o indicativo 351 não seja possível o utilizador apagá-lo, mas que seja possível à frente adicionar o número do cliente, por exemplo, 35191234455xx. Ao inserir na tabela, tem de inserir o indicativo e o número.

Comment: Você está pedindo ajuda para que um valor de input seja fixo e não possa ser modificado, mas também está dizendo que tem que ser possível adicionar o contato do cliente no `input`. Você poderia esclarecer melhor isso? Este campo fixo é campo que o cliente tem que alterar?

Comment: @fernandosavio pretendo que o indicativo **351** não seja possível o utilizador apaga-lo, mas que seja possível à frente adicionar o número do cliente, por exemplo, **35191234455xx**. Ao inserir na tabela, tem de inserir o indicativo e o número

Comment: Agora ficou mais fácil entender, o `351` é um prefixo obrigatório do campo, e o usuário pode preencher o restante. Pergunta, está utilizando algum framework CSS? Dica: Edita sua pergunta e coloca essa última informação que você me passou, pois ela é crítica para entender seu problema.

Comment: @fernandosavio não estou a utilizar nenhum framework CSS

Comment: E por que não apresente o valor **fora** do `<input>` e o adicione ao valor no *backend*? Coloque esse valor em um `<span>`, por exemplo.

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss, utilizei a sua dica, obrigado. Só uma dúvida, e ao inserir na base de dados, também insere o valor que está dentro do `<span>`?

Comment: Não vai inserir o que tem dentro do span. O que o @AndersonCarlosWoss quis dizer é que na hora de inserir no banco de dados, você inclua o número + o que foi digitado, por exemplo: `insert into tabela (telefone) values ('351$telefone')`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já que é um número fixo que não deve ser alterado, coloque-o fora do input, onde o utilizador irá apenas inserir o resto dos números nesse input, algo assim:

```html
351 <input type="tel" name="telemovel">
```

No back-end (PHP) você verifica se o utilizador informou o número corretamente e concatena o "351" ao número:

```
$telemovel = $_POST['telemovel'];
if(!empty($telemovel)) $telemovel = '351'.$telemovel;
```

Desta forma, se o valor de `$telemovel` estiver vazio, não será inserido nada na coluna da tabela onde você quer guardar esse número.

Answer (score 2):

Bem não sei se esse é o melhor jeito de se fazer.
Eu criei uma `div` simulando o `input`, com o `input readonly`dentro e com outro `input text`ao lado assim possibilitando editar o valor apos o 351.

```html
<style>.read {
  border: none;
  width: 20px !important;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.ajuste{
  width: 77.5% !important;
}

div.input {
  width: 155px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 0.3px solid gray;
} </style>
   
<div class="input">
  <input type="text" readonly id="Contato" class="read" name="Contato" value="351" required>
  <input class="read ajuste">
</div>
```

Comment: Otavio, a resposta é boa, porém o `disabled` faz com que o valor do input não seja enviado quando o form for submetido. Esse detalhe é bem importante e não pode ser ignorado. Seria legal você colocar os links da documentação do [`disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#disabled) e do [`readonly`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text#attr-readonly). (Esse comentário é só para melhorar a informação. Se você adicionar estes detalhes na resposta eu apago :D )

Comment: Bem lembrado Fernando, já ia comentar a mesma coisa sobre o uso do **disabled**, seu uso pode gerar dores de cabeça futuras, experiencia própria.

Comment: Essas duas opções não são possíveis, por que no caso pretendo que o valor do indicativo seja inserido na tabela da base de dados e também tem de ter permissão para adicionar o contato do cliente.

Answer (score -1):

Eu fiz algo parecido, e funcionou

```js
const telefone = document.querySelector('#cad-tel')
  let indicativo = '+55(11) '

  telefone.addEventListener('input', checkNumber)
  telefone.addEventListener('focus', () => {
  //Define o valor da variável indicativo no input ao focar, caso o valor seja vazio
    if(telefone.value == ''){
        telefone.value = indicativo   
      }
  })
  
  function checkNumber(){
    //Testa os primeiros caracteres no input, caso não seja o indicativo, seta o valor para o indicativo
    if(telefone.value.substring(0, 7) != ''){
      if(telefone.value.split(' ')[1] == undefined)
        telefone.value = indicativo
      else
        telefone.value = indicativo + telefone.value.split(' ')[1]      
    }
  }
```

```html
<label for="cad-tel">Telefone</label>
          <input type="tel" id="cad-tel" placeholder="+55(11) 900000000" required onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57"/>
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).